# Distributing Cell Data

Tags: sql, vba, excel, sql-server-2008

I wrote some code today for work and I've ran into an issue where the command I provide the SQL server through VBA doesn't solicit the same quantity of information as if I were to execute the same exact command on the server itself.  If I execute the code below in VBA, I get about 25 rows of 68 columns.  If I execute the same command on the server itself, I get just over 1500 rows of 68 columns.  What I'm doing is selecting either an order number or a date, in a form, and stripping the mountain of data to just what my customer is looking to find.  I'm sure this isn't the best way to distribute data across a spreadsheet.  I'm looking for suggestions and error corrections!

Thanks in advance,

Adam

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
constr = "Provider=REMOVEDFORPRIVACY"
If (ComboBox1.Value <> "" And ComboBox2.Value <> "") Or (ComboBox1.Value = "" And ComboBox2.Value = "") Then
    MsgBox "Please select one search method.", vbOKOnly
    ComboBox2.Value = ""
    ComboBox1.Value = ""
ElseIf (ComboBox1.Value <> "" And ComboBox2.Value = "") Then
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Run_Data].[dbo].[RunLog_Data] WHERE SnapShot_Date = '" & ComboBox1.Value & "'"
    conn.Open constr
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    Set rst = cmd.Execute()
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        o = o + 1
        If o > 67 Then
            o = 1                   'Column Position
            n = n + 1               'Row Position
        End If
        Range(Cells(n, o), Cells(n, o)).Value = rst(o)
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close
    conn.Close
ElseIf (ComboBox1.Value = "" And ComboBox2.Value <> "") Then
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Run_Data].[dbo].[RunLog_Data] WHERE OrderNumber = '" & ComboBox2.Value & "'"
    conn.Open constr
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    Set rst = cmd.Execute()
    Do While Not rst.EOF
       'Duplicate above and consolidate code
    rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close
    conn.Close
End If
```

Comment: Instead of `Do While Not rst.EOF` ... `Loop`, you can possibly just say `Cells(n, o).CopyFromRecordSet rst`.  (I think)  (e.g. `Cells(2,1).CopyFromRecordSet rst` should [hopefully] copy the recordset starting from cell A2)

Comment: Dang, thanks.  Don't know how I missed that.  Cleaned it up as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that you are performing your `rst.MoveNext` after you have filled in each **cell**.  Therefore in your first line of output you are picking up the first column of the first record, the second column of the second record, ... the 68th column of the 68th record.  Then you are populating the second line of output with the 1st column of the 69th record, etc.

I believe you can replace your entire loop with

```
Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset rst
```

(replacing the Cells(1,1) with whatever cell you want to be the top-lefthand corner of your results)

but alternatively you could move your `rst.MoveNext` command inside your If statement, i.e.

```
   If o > 67 Then
        o = 1                   'Column Position
        n = n + 1               'Row Position
        rst.MoveNext
   End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub acceptButton_Click()
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    constr = "REMOVEDFORPRIVACY"
    Dim sel_str, sel_type As String
    If (ComboBox1.Value <> "" And ComboBox2.Value <> "") Or (ComboBox1.Value = "" And ComboBox2.Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Please select one search method.", vbOKOnly
        ComboBox2.Value = ""
        ComboBox1.Value = ""
    ElseIf (ComboBox1.Value <> "" And ComboBox2.Value = "") Then
        sel_type = "SnapShot_Date"
        sel_str = ComboBox1.Value
    ElseIf (ComboBox1.Value = "" And ComboBox2.Value <> "") Then
        sel_type = "OrderNumber"
        sel_str = ComboBox2.Value
    End If
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Run_Data].[dbo].[RunLog_Data] WHERE " & sel_type & " = '" & sel_str & "'"
    conn.Open constr
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    Set rst = cmd.Execute()
        Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst
    rst.Close
    conn.Close
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```